# Docker containers inaccessible in browser after reboot - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: docker

Raspberry Pi 4
Raspberry Pi OS Lite
Docker 23.0.0

Docker containers are not accessible in the browser after reboot, I thought it may have been because the containers do not start, but it appears that they do. But I am not sure why they are inaccessible. As an attempted remedy, I ran the following commands:

```
docker run -d --restart always [Container]
```

or just:

```
docker start [Container]
```

The only solution I can seem to find is to reinstall the container, but that is useless because I lose data and have to set up the application again, after every reboot.

Here's what I've done:

I first checked the running containers:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   2 minutes ago   Up About a minute   8080/tcp                                   elegant_bhabha
```

Focussing on the searxng you can see it is running:

cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   2 minutes ago   Up About a minute   8080/tcp

Then I try to restart Searxng just to see if it will make it work in the browser:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ docker restart elegant_bhabha
elegant_bhabha
```

I proceed to check to see if Searxng has started and is accessible at 192.168.50.168:8080 in the browser, it is not.

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   3 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   8080/tcp                                   elegant_bhabha
```

Then I re-do the installation process to get it to work:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ cd my-instance
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ export PORT=8080
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ docker pull searxng/searxng
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from searxng/searxng
Digest: sha256:3d656c623ce5293633e4e0d7fcf4bc47e17dc4dc13d4300173b57b0d73879270
Status: Image is up to date for searxng/searxng:latest
docker.io/searxng/searxng:latest
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ docker run --rm \
             -d -p ${PORT}:8080 \
             -v "${PWD}/searxng:/etc/searxng" \
             -e "BASE_URL=http://localhost:$PORT/" \
             -e "INSTANCE_NAME=my-instance" \
             searxng/searxng
8b914f2122817a3f301fa0b550ccc600426728fe30098ae845d950547f1fa9b0
```

As you can see below, there is a change after reinstalling the container, after reinstallation the container is now accessible in the browser at 192.168.50.168:8080, but of course I have to again set up the application. I have to do this for every docker container I install after every reboot.

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
8b914f212281   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   15 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   gifted_gagarin
cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   7 minutes ago    Up 6 minutes    8080/tcp                                  elegant_bhabha
```

Every time I install any container, it works fine and is accessible in the browser. And then after reboot they don't work, and running restart commands doesn't work. I have no idea how to resolve this, any ideas?

Comment: @goldilocks Is it okay to take a look at my edited post again, and again sorry for making it difficult in my original post.

Comment: the difference in PORTS property is interesting

Comment: I don't think you are going to get much help here with this.  It is almost certainly something to do with the port mapping from the container, which involves a virtual interface; you don't seem to have thought about this at all, I think you should be looking at the ip NAT table, etc.  However, I haven't used docker in years (I converted to LXC), and no one else here has chimed in.  Also, the brand of hardware is irrelevant.  You should ask further about this on 
[Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I haven't thought about what you mentioned because I am a beginner with Linux and Terminal in general. I don't even understand what you wrote, so I'll google some of it and look for help elsewhere.